# PyInstaller dist EXE disappears

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Was given a choice to build a GUI application for a scientific project and I chose PyQt and PyInstaller to design, build and distribute the application.

Now I have created a GUI application using PyQt5 that came with Anaconda distribution. I have created an EXE using PyInstaller for my first GUI application and used the following command to create the EXE.

```
pyinstaller -wF main.spec
```

I run the above command in the project directory using PyCharm terminal.

However, once I run the exe by either double-click or through CMD using admin privileges, it just disappears. No error mentioned on the console or fatal error exceptions dialogs displayed. It just disappears. Why does this happen, and what should I do about this.

NOTE: using *pyinstaller - 3.5*

```
SPEC file:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Python-Sandbox-Honai'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Comment: It probably has an error in the build, but the console closes before you can read it. I usually make a batch file and run it with a pause.

Comment: @tgikal Should I make a batch file to create the EXE ? Or make a batch file to run the already exisisting EXE to see what's causing the problem? If it is the latter, how can I create a batch file for an exe?

Comment: Just make a batch (.bat) file, make the first line the `path\to\the\file.exe`, and the second line `pause`, then run the batch file and it will leave the terminal up so you can read the error.

Comment: Or even easier open a command prompt and type `cmd /K "C:\Path\To\App.exe"`

Comment: @tgikal Done. Nothing. No error messages, in fact no messages at all. Just goes to "Press any key to continue..."

Comment: At this point you'd have to provide more details of whats in your .spec file.

Comment: @tgikal I've updated the post. Please check.

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues in the spec file, I'd suspect you're missing a call in the script to actually start the functions of the script or wait for input.